# Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 - screen lock

Tags: upgrade, lock-screen, 22.04

locked out during ubuntu 22.04 upgrade. hp laptop. i type password to unlock but nothing happening after pressing enter. Can't force restart as this might affect ongoing installation.

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same problem.
Fortunately there were two accounts in my laptop.
I got a terminal with Ctrl-Alt F3 from the lock screen.
I login into to the second account because the password for the account where upgrade script was running was not recognized.
After that, I was able to unlock the screen via command line, as follows:

```
loginctl list-sessions
```

(will give you the active sessions in your system).

```
loginctl unlock-session XX
```

(where XX is the number of the session with the upgrade script is running).

Then it asked for the password to unlock the session, but this time it was recognized. After that I was able to access my session without further issues.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has to do with the display server you use. In the login screen there should be an option to switch between xorg and wayland, maybe the one not selected works?

Saw a similar issue [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GLhJM8V_2g&t=255s)